# I am not able to generate namespaces with composer. Additionally, files are loaded using autoload_static

Tags: composer-php

I am not able to generate namespaces with composer. Additionally, files are loaded using autoload_static instead of autoload_files, autoload_namespaces, ...

composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "core\\" : "/src/core/",
            "CrmBundle\\Entity\\" : "/src/CrmBundle/Entity/",
            "CrmBundle\\Controller\\" : "/src/CrmBundle/Controller/"

        },
        "classmap": [
            "src/core/App.php",
            "src/core/View.php",
            "src/core/Controller.php"
        ]
    },    

    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "symfony/console": "~2.5",
        "twig/twig": "^1.24",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.1"
    }  
}
```

Generated autoload_namespaces:

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Twig_' => array($vendorDir . '/twig/twig/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\ORM\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/orm/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\DBAL\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/dbal/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Lexer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/lexer/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Inflector\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/inflector/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/collections/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/annotations/lib'),
);
```

First, there is no my namespaces. Second, the generated namespaces are not loaded, because for some reason in autoload_real, the loading goes through autoload_static

```
$useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION');
if ($useStaticLoader) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';
    print_r(" <br> static_loafing"); //i see this in index.php
    call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit26d4625e30b8fe554b6b94853829798f::getInitializer($loader));
} else {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your autoloading paths must not start with a slash! They have to be relative to the position of your `composer.json` file. Most likely you'd simply remove the slashes and it will work.

The reason your autoloading uses `autoload_static.php` is because you are using PHP 5.6 or later. This version offers a way to do autoloading very efficiently, so Composer uses this to speed things up. No need to worry about this, it is not part of your problem.